# How does one obtain the Staff of Wisdom?

Tags: dark-souls-2

I was perusing the Dark Souls wiki when I found the comparative list of Staves in the game, but three (now two) of the staves did not have wiki pages, only their stats. Those staves are Staff of Armana, and the most powerful looking, Staff of Wisdom. Without a page for this item, I haven't any clue how to go about getting it. Where does one find it? Is it from a quest, or killing a friendly NPC?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jAgyUY3nJk8) describing how to get the Staff of Wisdom. You start at

> Dragon Shrine

after the first enemy there is a Pharros Lockstone port. Unlock it to reveal a hidden wall which has the chest containing the Staff of Wisdom.